# Issues with screen not coming on when Mac is running

Tags: display, sleep-wake, mac-mini, displayport

I run a Late 2012 Mac Mini running 10.13 High Sierra with a Dell QHD monitor via DisplayPort. I've seen two different cases where as far as I can tell the Mac is running (HDD light flashing, etc) but the monitor shows as idle:

1. When it goes to sleep from lack of use, the monitor sometimes won't wake up (like once every few weeks, I leave it always-on). I already run `caffeinate -s` in a console window and I think the Mac itself is running, but sometimes the monitor thinks otherwise and I have to reboot.
2. Today, I turned the Mac on for the first time since turning it off over Christmas - first cold start for a while. The monitor didn't come on, just sat in standby mode (not no-signal). I pulled the DP cable and plugged it back in and now it came to life, which doesn't work in case 1 above.

These things make for a really annoying start to the day and I can never find what might be wrong. I already chased some ideas - I thought the Mac was going into deep sleep and not waking, but now I am fairly convinced the Mac is running but not waking the monitor and I don't know what to try next.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your cables are good and connected firmly, I would try resetting the NVRAM and SMC (in that order).

**Resetting NVRAM**

Your Mac use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM) to store a whole range of settings. Here’s how to reset this:

1. **Fully shut down your Mac mini**
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys. You have to make sure you press these keys **before** the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime for the second time
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac mini reboot normally

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

**Resetting SMC on a Mac mini**

Follow these steps for resetting the SMC on your Mac Pro:

1. Fully Shut Down your Mac min
2. Unplug the AC power cord
3. Wait at least 15 seconds
4. Plug the AC power cord back in
5. Wait at least 5 seconds
6. Switch on your Mac mini

Now use your Mac mini as usual to determine if the problem still occurs.